# Program Not producing desired outcome

Tags: c++, if-statement

I need to calculate how many containers and boxes there are for an order of cookies. 75 boxes per container, and 24 cookies per box. Both need to have their specified amounts in them so if there're remainders, I need to state how many boxes couldn't fill a container and how many cookies were left over. My code is getting stuck right after I input the total number of cookies ordered.

Input for code is: 2001
Output should be: 83 total boxes, 1 container, 8 remaining boxes, and 9 leftover cookies.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int ContBoxes = 75;
const int BoxCookies = 24;

int main() {
    int TotCookies;
    int TotContainers = 0;
    int TotBoxes = 0;
    int RemBoxes = 0;

    cout << "Input number of cookies ordered: ";
    cin >> TotCookies;

    if (TotCookies >= 1800) {
        TotContainers += 1;
        TotCookies -= 1800;
    } else if ((TotCookies >= 24) && (TotCookies < 1800)) {
        RemBoxes += 1;
        TotCookies -= 24;
    } else if (TotCookies < 24) {
    }
    cout << "Your order consists of " << TotContainers << " Containers, "
         << TotBoxes << " Total Boxes, " << RemBoxes
         << " Boxes That couldn't fit in containers, and " << TotCookies
         << " Cookies that couldn't fit in boxes.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please run this code through an autoformatter. Seeing the structure is the first step in understanding the code. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: May I recommend [clang format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)? Because your current code formatting is bad.

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt, Jesper Juhl I apologize, but I have no idea what you mean by my formatting. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hint:  Only one of those blocks in braces will execute.  Also, the block that does execute will only execute once (i.e., at most one increment of containers or boxes).

Comment: @Prometheus At the very least, indent things consistently and so that they match the scope they are in.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some guidelines that will hopefully help you solve the problem. (Without giving it straight forward).

- What happens when there are 10,000 cookies? How many "containers"
  will your code produce?
- What is the total maximum number of containers your code can have for
  any given input? 
  <sub><sub><sub>(Hint: You are increasing it by one, once).</sub></sub></sub>
- Now, ask yourself the same questions for boxes....
- Another hint follows, but I encourage you to start by answering these...

<sub><sub><sub>Use the integer divide operator. For example, 50/24 will give you 2 - which is exactly what you are looking for when assigning to boxes....</sub></sub></sub>